# Custom htaccess 301 redirect with regexp

Tags: regex, http-status-code-301

I want to move pages from source url:

```
http://mysite.fr/topic/15530-fermeture-de-lapplication-sur-run/
```

to target url:

```
http://mysite.fr/index.php?p=discussion/15530/fermeture-de-lapplication-sur-run/
```

I tried this without success:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/topic/([0-9]+)-(.+?)$ /index.php?p=discussion/$1/$2
```

What did I miss ?
Thanks in advance.

For info, this raw redirect is working:

```
Redirect 301 /topic/15530-fermeture-de-lapplication-sur-run/ /index.php?p=discussion/15530/fermeture-de-lapplication-sur-run/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/topic/([0-9]+)-([^/]+/)$
```